# How to create a wave visualiser from AVPlayerItem? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, buffer

I have been using this https://github.com/teodorpatras/Jukebox library to help playing audio from URL but i have encountered a problem trying to create wave visualizer like this https://github.com/ApplikeySolutions/PandoraPlayer but it only allows playing from Music Library. In Pandora Player there is open source wave visualiser https://github.com/ApplikeySolutions/PandoraPlayer/issues/3 but it need to convert to some kind of buffer like this

```
public func audioPlayer(_ audioPlayer: EZAudioPlayer!, playedAudio buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>!, withBufferSize bufferSize: UInt32, withNumberOfChannels numberOfChannels: UInt32, in audioFile: EZAudioFile!) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
        self?.updatePlaybackStatus()
    }
    self.waveVisualizer?.updateWaveWithBuffer(buffer, withBufferSize: bufferSize, withNumberOfChannels: numberOfChannels)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

refer this https://github.com/alankarmisra/SwiftSiriWaveformView this will help you create waveform.

```
@IBOutlet weak var audioView: SwiftSiriWaveformView!
```

you could use

```
audioView.amplitude = 1.0
```

Installation (CocoaPods):

> SwiftSiriWaveformView is available through CocoaPods. To install it,
>   simply add the following lines to your Podfile:
>
> For Cocoapods >= 1.0 use_frameworks! target "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME" do
>       pod "SwiftSiriWaveformView" end For Cocoapods < 1.0 use_frameworks! pod "SwiftSiriWaveformView"

Comment: Hi, Sachin this is a good way to visualize the music wave thanks , but if i use this i still have one problem left which is i am using AVPlayer to stream audio, i need to somehow make it link to the visualizer you sent me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this pod with Cocoa Pods `pod 'SpeechRecognizerButton'`
Awesome thing and simply customizing.

Link: https://github.com/alexruperez/SpeechRecognizerButton

Comment: This is nice , but this only can be use for input audio from outside, i need to get the internal audio of the current streaming songs then manipulate the waveform. Any idea how to do that ?